# Scoring email engagement across a series of email campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We are looking to launch a "Welcome Series" which will be made up of a sequence of independent email campaigns across a 24 month period.

If a recipient opens one of these emails I would like to record this somewhere as a score. If they then click a link then the score should increase. I want to be able to specific which campaigns include this feature, and also weight certain campaigns or actions differently. The idea being that X months after joining we have an indication of how much they have engaged with the "Welcome Series" and can then adjust our ongoing communications accordingly.

This scoring could either be real time (at point of action) or via an automation on a daily basis to recalculate the scores. It is okay that zero activity recipients don't have a score (of zero) captured.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I guess the question would be "Is it possible to score email engagement across a series of emails from within SFMC? And if so, how could this be done"

Answer (score 1):

Very Interesting scenario! As you must be aware, when a recipient interacts with the email (Clicks, Opens, Unsubscribes etc.), Marketing Cloud records those actions immediately in its database and all of these are available using data views and tracking export.

To achieve your requirements, I think you will have to build this logic using queries and data extensions. If you have an external reporting system, I suggest get all of this data out of SFMC and then do all the computations. That would be much easier and manageable.

Campaign level tracking is still not mature in SFMC. I also struggle here. There is a Campaign Email Tracking report which might come to some help.
Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I guess I was hoping to manage the engagement score automatically, and also store that score within SFMC so that we could use it drive different communications.

Answer (score 0):

Try Measures!

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/measures/

You can set these up to count customers' activity (or lack thereof) with your mailings, and they can easily be used in Data Filters to produce ongoing records of who's doing what.

You can also define the mailing ID's, API keys, timeframes and lots of other criteria to get what you want.

Give it a look, probably easier than queries etc.